# AceFEM: How to mirror a domain in postprocessing?

Tags: packages, finite-element-method, postprocessing, acegen

Note: This question is about [AceFEM package](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/acefem/) for finite element analysis in Mathematica.

In finite element analyses we usually take advantage of symmetry of geometry and loading to model only a portion of computational domain. `SMTShowMesh` only shows this explicitly modeled portion of domain. How can I plot results of analysis over the whole domain in the postprocessing phase?

Bellow I have prepared a test function that stretches a square domain with symmetry BC on axis X and axis Y.

```
<< AceFEM`;

(* A test function. Its argument is the number of elements on one edge. *)
Clear[testAnalysis]
testAnalysis[n_Integer] := Module[{},
  SMTInputData[];
  SMTAddDomain["test", 
   "OL:SEPEQ1DFHYQ1NeoHooke", {"E *" -> 1000., "\[Nu] *" -> 0.3}];
  SMTMesh["test", "Q1", {n, n}, {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}}];
  SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{ "X" == 0 &, 1 -> 0}, {"Y" == 0 &, 
    2 -> 0}, { "Y" == 1 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0.5}];
  SMTAnalysis[];
  SMTNextStep["\[Lambda]" -> 1];
  While[SMTConvergence[10^-8, 10], SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  ]

(* Execute test analysis. *)
testAnalysis[2]
```

Standard use of `SMTShowMesh` plots only explicitly modeled part (one quarter) of the domain. How can I plot the whole assumed domain?

```
SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions" -> True, "Contour" -> True, 
 "DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Eyy", "Mesh" -> White, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, ImageSize -> 200, 
 Ticks -> None]
```

[image: mesh image]

Comment: You can look at examples for the visualization of [PeriodicBoundaryCondition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html) to get an idea how this could be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of any built in options that would automatically mirror the domain over a specified plane / line. One solution is to add additional transformed plots of mesh through the option `SMTShowMesh["User"->...]`. Disadvantage of this approach is that you have to think about how to correctly transform values of the field you are plotting. `SMTShowMesh["Field"->...]` plots a scalar field, but this may be just a component of another vector field (displacements) or tensor field (stress, strain).

First we run a test analysis to produce some results with the function defined in the OP question. Then we collect necessary quantities to shorten the syntax.

```
<< AceFEM`;
testAnalysis[2];

X = SMTNodeData["X"];(* initial position of nodes *)
u = SMTNodeData["at"];(* displacements of nodes *)
(* TransformationFunction[] for mirroring over Y axis. *)
rtY = ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}];

(* Get a suitable range of values for creating a contour lines and 
the legend. Shear strain "Exy" is chosen for example. *)
limit = 0.85*Max[Abs[SMTPostData["Exy"]]]
```

This shows the domain mirrored over Y axis. Multiple mirrored domains can be added like this `"User"->{ First@SMTShowMesh[...], First@SMTShowMesh[...], ...  }`.

```
SMTShowMesh[
 "DeformedMesh" -> True,
 "Field" -> "Exy",
 "Contour" -> {-limit, limit, 6},
 (* Add another SMTShowMesh for option "User"->... *)
 "User" -> First@SMTShowMesh[
    (* Subtract initial coodinates, then add transformed initial coordinates
     and (if needed) add transformed displacements. *)
    "DeformedMesh" -> Transpose[-X + (rtY /@ X) + (rtY /@ u)],
    (* Transformation of field values. (Multiply shear strain "Exy" by -1) *)
    "Field" -> -SMTPostData["Exy"],
    (* Range of "Contour" has to be set explicity to include the negative interval. *)
    "Contour" -> {-limit, limit, 6},
    "Legend" -> False
    ],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
 ImageSize -> 300,
 Ticks -> None
 ]
```

[image: mirrored mesh]

Same approach can be used for showing domains with periodic symmetry.

```
(* This intentionally shows overlapping domains to emphasis rotational transform. *)
rot = RotationTransform[Pi/3, {0, 0}];

SMTShowMesh[
 "DeformedMesh" -> True,
 "Field" -> None,
 "User" -> First@SMTShowMesh[
    "DeformedMesh" -> Transpose[-X + (rot /@ X) + (rot /@ u)],
    "Field" -> None
    ],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
 ImageSize -> 300,
 Ticks -> None
 ]
```

[image: rotated mesh]

My code just shows basic approach to the problem and not a comprehensive solution, especially with respect to transforming the `"Field"->...`  values. Ideally we could have just another option to `SMTShowMesh` to take care of everything (e.g. `SMTShowMesh[..., "some option name"->{ reflection transform 1, reflection transform 2,...}]` ).

---

EDIT:

Alternative solution to plot the whole domain was proposed by @user21 in the comments to the question. We can map geometric transformation to `Graphics` expression (at appropriate position) and show multiple plots together with `Show`.

```
(* Important fact: Plot is for "Exy" component of strain tensor field. *)
mesh = SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions" -> True, "Contour" -> True, 
  "DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Exy", "Legend" -> False, 
  "Mesh" -> White, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
  ImageSize -> 150, Ticks -> None]
```

This solution is elegant and flexible, but it doesn't transform field values of vector and tensor fields. It works for scalar fields.

```
(* geometric transformation functions for reflection over X and Y axis *)
flipX = GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}]] &;
flipY = GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]] &;

(* Warning! Domain geometry is transformed correctly, but field values are not.  *)
Show[
 mesh,
 MapAt[flipX, mesh, 1],
 MapAt[Composition[flipY, flipX], mesh, 1],
 MapAt[flipY, mesh, 1],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot with Show]